# How can I shift the text up and make it start at the first line?

Tags: wrapfigure, wrap

Since I am new to this, I have problems with text layout and figures. Probably because I'm not using the codes correctly and lots of equation + figures. As you see in the picture, the text is shifting down a lot and I don't know how to fix it or correct it.

```
\documentclass{article}        
\begin{document}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig, amsmath}
\newpage
\begin{equation}
\begin{align}
\textrm{frequency}=$\omega$RC=1 \textrm {which is} R/2
\end{align}
\end{equation}

\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{figure/resultat/impedance_p.PNG}
        \caption{Schematic fig. of cell used for impedance measurement (källa)}
        \label{fig:p}
 \end{center} 
\end{wrapfigure} 

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{figure/resultat/impedance_S.PNG}
        \caption{Schematic fig. of cell used for impedance measurement (källa)}
        \label{fig:s}
 \end{center} 
\end{wrapfigure} 


 For parallel resistance R and capacitance C circuit will give semi-circle at Z$^*$ plane, however it's possible to obtain two or three semi-circle at Z$^*$ complex plane. This observation will be due to the parallel boundary resistance R$_b$, boundary capacitance C$_b$ and grain-boundary resistance R$_g_b$ , grain-boundary capacitance C$_b_g$. It's important to understand that each point on spike or semi-circle correspond to specific frequency value, the reason why it's also important to scan a range of frequency in order to produce the graph. With one frequency measured value, it's impossible to distinguish if it's spike or semi-circle phenomenal. 

Problems could be obtained if the electrodes are broken or if they touch each other. For example if a vertical spike is observed at low frequencies in the Z$^*$ complex plane, this could be explained as presence of a large capacitance in the series circuit. In other words, the electronic conductivity in the solid electrolyte is small compared to the ionic magnitude of the electrolyte.

[The semi-circle result could be explained as following (fig 13,27), either the equivalent circuit doesn't containing a large series capacitor or capacitance is observed at the Z$^*$ complex plane] 


In order to understand the plotted complex plane data, the measurement are reading several corresponding to series resistans R$_s$ and series capacitance C$_s$. These measurement could be converted and calculated to impedance using this equation:
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a single `wrapfigure` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}        
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-9x16}
\caption{Schematic fig. of cell used for impedance measurement (källa)\label{fig:p}}

\bigskip

\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-9x16}
\caption{Schematic fig. of cell used for impedance measurement (källa)\label{fig:s}}

\end{wrapfigure} 

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]